# How to get data from react-persist and save it back in redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I tried to implement Redux-Persist and this is the code I wrote:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { usersReducer } from './users';
import { eventsReducer } from './events';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
}

const reducer = combineReducers({ users: usersReducer, events: eventsReducer })

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

My **store.js** file:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { usersReducer } from './users';
import { eventsReducer } from './events';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
}

const reducer = combineReducers({ users: usersReducer, events: eventsReducer })

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

My **usersReducer.js** file (*eventsReducer.js* is built like this one):

```
const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    thisUser: []
}

export function usersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'users/loggedIn':
            return { ...state, loggedIn: action.payload }
        case 'users/addUser':
            return { ...state, thisUser: action.payload[0] }
        case 'users/setActivated':
            return { ...state, thisUser: { ...state.thisUser, activated: action.payload } }
        case 'clearAll':
            return {
                thisUser: []
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My **index.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store, persistor } from './store/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**My problem is**: Redux-Persist works and is saved in localStorage, but when I refresh the page, my data saved in localStorage with Redux-Persist don't update my local state and will be empty. I think that on any refresh of the page I should get persisted data from localStorage and send back into my Redux state.

I don't know if is correct what I say but I need help how to resolve this problem.

Comment: This is something what redux-persist will do on it own so our data doesn't get lost on reload. Can you make sure the you have wrapped your app inside PersistGate?

Comment: I updated the code and now you can see that I used PersistGate in my code. What I have to do?

Comment: Strange, It should persist data that you have but i will suggest use the whitelist option to persist the only reducers that you need to persist and also try changing the persist key to the `primary` instead of `root`.